# Qt class as the return type in QSettings().value(...) produces SystemError

Tags: python, qsettings, pyside6

The following code raises `SystemError: <built-in method value of PySide6.QtCore.QSettings object at 0x...> returned NULL without setting an error` at the last line.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor

s: QSettings = QSettings('StackOverflow', 'Logo')
s.value('thickness', 3.0, float)
s.value('color', QColor('#f48024'), QColor)
```

However, if I omit the return type and use just

```py
s.value('color', QColor('#f48024'))
```

everything goes fine and returns `QColor`. What's wrong with `QColor` as a type? Actually, the error appears with every Qt class name used as a return type in `QSettings`.

Python 3.9.6 on Fedora, PySide6 is 6.1.2, inside a `venv`.
With Python 3.8 on Kubuntu, however, I did not experience such a problem two days ago. I'll update the question as soon as I check the packages used there.

**Update:** Same with Python 3.8.10 on Kubuntu, PySide6 from 6.1.0 to 6.1.2. My memory does betray me.

Comment: It looks like a PySide6 bug, I recommend you report it. Note: The code that does the conversion is this: https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/PySide6/glue/qtcore.cpp#n49, from what I see it does a conversion with only some basic types such as list, bytes, string, etc. but it does not cover the cases of QtTypes

Comment: The issue opened here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1619